# Pandas group by

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like so -

```
     Name    Id
7   Retail  1980
8   Retail  1980
9   Retail  1980
10  Retail  1980
11  Retail  1980
```

When I run this

```
df.groupby('Name')
```

I expect

```
     Name    Id
1   Retail  1980
```

But the output is

```
     Name    Id
7   Retail  1980
8   Retail  1980
9   Retail  1980
10  Retail  1980
11  Retail  1980
```

Can someone explain how to get my desired output and why pandas groupby functions this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, I believe you want `first()`. Just using `df.groupby('Name')` will return a groupby object. You can use the `groups` property of the groupby object to return a dictionary of the groups:

```
df.groupby('Name')

df.groupby('Name').groups

df.groupby('Name').first()
```

Returns:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x00000238D8008898>

{'Retail': Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')}

          Id
Name        
Retail  1980
```